# request.getRequestDispatcher não está funcionando e não apresenta erros

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlet, java-bean

Estou com um problema no **request.getRequestDispatcher("Valida.jsp").forward(request, response);** do meu servlet que não da forward para a pagina Valida.jsp. Eu preciso passar de um HTML para um javascript (por Ajax) que passa as infos para um Servlet e esse servlet grava os dados em um JavaBeans e da foward pra um jsp mostrar os dados. Não dá erro nehum de console ou de compilação. SImplesmente fica parado na pagina html principal.

Meu Servlet está assim:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    Beans beans = new Beans();
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String senha = request.getParameter("senha"); 
    String Pnome= request.getParameter("Pnome");
    String Mnome= request.getParameter("Mnome");
    String Snome= request.getParameter("Snome");

    beans.setEmail(email);
    beans.setSenha(senha);
    beans.setPnome(Pnome);
    beans.setMnome(Mnome);
    beans.setSnome(Snome);

    request.setAttribute("beans", beans);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("Valida.jsp").forward(request, response);
    System.out.println("passou do forward");
}
```

Meu JAVASCRIPT

```js
count = 0;
onload = inicia;

function inicia() {

  document.getElementById("idCadastra").addEventListener("click", conecta, false);
}

function conecta() {

  var email = document.getElementById("idEmail").value;
  var senha = document.getElementById("idSenha").value;
  var Pnome = document.getElementById("idPrimeiroNome").value;
  var Mnome = document.getElementById("idNomeDoMeio").value;
  var Snome = document.getElementById("idSobreNome").value;

  if (email != "" && senha != "" && Pnome != "" && Snome != "") {
    console.log("entrou na conexão")
    httpRequest = createRequest();
    httpRequest.open("GET", "Servlet?email=" + email + "&senha=" + senha + "&Pnome=" + Pnome + "&Mnome=" + Mnome + "&Snome=" + Snome, true);
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
        if (httpRequest.status == 200) {

        }
      }
    }
    httpRequest.send(null);
  }

}
```

```html
-------MEU HTML-------

<td class="td" align="right" width="300">
  Ainda não é usuário? Crie o seu Login:

  <form method="get">

    e-mail:
    <input id="idEmail" type="text" name="e-mail" required="required">*
    <br>Senha:
    <input id="idSenha" type="text" name="senha" required="required">*
    <br>Repita Senha:
    <input id="idRepitaSenha" type="text" name="repitasenha" required="required">*
    <br>Primeiro Nome:
    <input id="idPrimeiroNome" type="text" name="primeironome" required="required">*
    <br>Nome do Meio:
    <input id="idNomeDoMeio" type="text" name="nomedomeio">&nbsp&nbsp
    <br>Sobrenome:
    <input id="idSobreNome" type="text" name="sobrenome" required="required">*
    <br>

  </form>
  <button class="inputCriarLogin" id="idCadastra" name="criarlogin">Criar Login</button>
```

Comment: Vinicius, aparentemente está tudo ok. Você precisa verificar o log do servidor pra saber se está dando alguma exceção.
Algumas perguntas: o que a função `createRequest();` faz exatamente?
O `Valida.jsp` tem que estar no mesmo nível da Servlet para funcionar o caminho dessa forma, coloque sempre `/caminho-jsp/arquivo.jsp`, no seu caso: `/Valida.jsp`.\
Coloque um `println` antes de dar o forward e verifique se está ao menos chegando dentro da Servlet.
Mais uma coisa, coloque um `console.log` na primeira linha da função `onreadystatechange` e verifique a saida.

Comment: Andrew, obrigado pela resposta. Eu retirei os **console.log()** e **println()** do código para ficar mais fácil de entender. Eu não recebo nenhuma exceção em nenhum lugar. Verifiquei através de **println()** e meu servlet está recebendo todos os valores dos campos do form do meu html. Inclusive botei um **println** antes e depois de **request.getRequestDispatcher("Valida.jsp")...** para ver se estava passando pelo mesmo e está tudo certo.

Quanto ao **createRequest();** faz parte da rotina do Ajax para pedir abrir uma conexão com o servlet. Algo do tipo.

Comment: Se não está dando exceção na hora de dar o Dispatch e você tem certeza que está chegando dentro do seu Servlet, significa que o Servlet está encontrando o arquivo e despachando corretamente. Pode seu httpRequest não recebendo corretamente a resposta do servidor.
Você poderia fazer um teste com objeto de xmlhttprequest? Verificar se está recebendo corretamente o response.